# struts-2.5.13 - conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.convertValue conversion error for locale fr_FR

Tags: struts2-interceptors

I am getting an error:

> Unparseable number: "10.00" at position 2

Here the value 10 entered in text field(UI). The same working fine with locale en_US.

Log trace :

com.opensymphony.xwork2.XWorkException: Unparseable number: "10.00" at position 2
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter.convertToDouble(NumberConverter.java:108) ~[struts2-core-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter.convertValue(NumberConverter.java:29) ~[struts2-core-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter.convertValue(NumberConverter.java:65) ~[struts2-core-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.doConvertToNumber(XWorkBasicConverter.java:205) ~[struts2-core-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkBasicConverter.convertValue(XWorkBasicConverter.java:108) ~[struts2-core-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter.convertValue(XWorkConverter.java:311) [struts2-core-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.convertValue(OgnlTypeConverterWrapper.java:39) [struts2-core-2.5.13.jar:2.5.13]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedType(OgnlRuntime.java:1218) [ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getConvertedTypes(OgnlRuntime.java:1235) [ognl-3.1.15.jar:?]

Comment: In order to help, we really need to be able to see the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: I havn't implemented any codes for conversion. This is happening from the framework side, I am including the log trace for details,

Answer (score 0):

The error is obvious since France belongs to the [countries using Arabic numerals with decimal comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma)

```
String number = "20,981";
try {
    double dNumber = Double.parseDouble(number.replace('.', ','));
    System.out.println("My double is " + dNumber);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("I got exception for invalid string " + number);
}
```

You may also like to enforce a specific number format:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("1,234");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```